# TypeError: getState is not a function in redux when trying to pass token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I hit the button in a page to pass the search results + authentication token, I get the following error

```
TypeError: getState is not a function
```

I attached the image as it shows an exact trace of the error.

How can I solve this ?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the full source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
export const searchResults = (name) =>
    (dispatch, getState) => {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?name=${name}, tokenConfig(getState))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is that in `SearchBar.js` you're calling `actions.searchResults(name)`. Then in `researcher.js` you're calling `tokenConfig` with `getState` which is the second parameter, but since `searchResults` was only called with one argument it's `undefined`. So finally in `auth.js` invoking `getState()` is erroring because it's `undefined`.

It likely isn't the functionality you want but you could test this theory by calling `actions.searchResults(name, () => ({ auth: { token: "test" } }))` to verify.

Otherwise, adding an `undefined` check. For example `token = getState && getState().auth.token` would at least prevent this error but my push it elsewhere.